# Arduino and Azure mobile app

Tags: azure, arduino, arduino-uno

How to send data to Azure mobile app easy tables from arduino code

Thanks

Comment: So, what have you tried so far and what didn't work?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13231/what-does-do-you-haz-teh-codez-mean

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the easy table and the arduino sensor data ready, use the following code in your loop:

```
char *server = "your-service.azurewebsites.net";
int value = arduino-data;
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {

    Serial.print("sending ");
    Serial.println(value);

    // POST URI
    sprintf(buffer, "POST https://your-service.azurewebsites.net/Tables/easy-table-name HTTP/1.1");
    client.println(buffer);

    // Host header
    sprintf(buffer, "Host: %s", server);
    client.println(buffer);

    client.println("Accept: application/json");
    // JSON content type
    client.println("Content-Type: application/json");

    sprintf(buffer, "{\"value\": %d}", value);

    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.println(strlen(buffer));
    client.println("ZUMO-API-VERSION: 2.0.0" );
    // End of headers
    client.println();

    // Request body
    client.println(buffer);

  } else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
```